# Camel Framework loop capture

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have issue in  cronjob in camel framework

I am trying to handle the exception in case error was thrown but it throws error as follows
caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: cronJob, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.

can you please suggest where the issue comes from

```
##Cronjob
apache.cronjob=timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1
 from("cronJob")
        .log("Cronjob started. Contacting Isabel API.")
        .bean(CollectReportsProcessor.class)
        .log("** Looplength of cronjob: ${headers.looplength}")
        .loop(header("looplength"))
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${header.CamelLoopIndex} == 3"))
            .log("Loop CamelLoopIndex is more than 3. Exiting the route.")
            .stop() // Stop the route if loop length is less than 1
            .end()
            .bean(ToSftp.class)
            .log("Picking up account reports and sending them to sftp.")
            .log("**** Filename : ${headers.CamelFileName} Format: ${headers.FileFormat}")
            .log("Only CAMT-files are picked up, others will not be sent to BBS import")
            .choice()
            .when(header("FileFormat").contains("CAMT53")) // (is CAMT)
                        .doTry()
                        .marshal().pgp(PGP_EQUO_PUBLIC_PATH, PGP_EQUO_USERID)
                        .multicast()
                            .to(BBS_SERVER)
                            .log("Message sent to BBS_SERVER")
                            .to(KYRIBA_BANK_STM_OUT)
                            .log("Message sent to KYRIBA_BANK_STM_OUT")
                            .bean(StatusUpdateProcessor.class)
                    .endDoTry()
                        .doCatch(Exception.class)
                        .process(exchange -> {
                            statusUpdaterProcessor.processWithRetry(exchange);
                        exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, true);
                                })
                    .log("Failed to send message to BBS_SERVER. Retrying... ${headers.retryCount}")
            
                    .endChoice() // End of (is CAMT)
                    .choice()
                        .when(PredicateBuilder.or(
                                header("FileFormat").contains("COD"),
                                header("FileFormat").contains("940")
                            ))  //(is COD or 940)
                        .doTry()
                            .marshal().pgp(PGP_EQUO_PUBLIC_PATH, PGP_EQUO_USERID)                         
                            .log("MT940/COD file detected. Further processing to Kyriba.")
                            .to(KYRIBA_BANK_STM_OUT)                
                            .log("Message sent to KYRIBA_BANK_STM_OUT")
                            .bean(StatusUpdateProcessor.class)
                        .endDoTry()
                        .doCatch(Exception.class)
                        .process(exchange -> {
                            statusUpdaterProcessor.processWithRetry(exchange);
                        exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, true);
                                })
                        .log("Failed to send message to KYRIBA_BANK_STM_OUT. Retrying... ${headers.retryCount}")
                        .endChoice() // End of (is COD or 940)
                    .endChoice() // End of inner choice
            //.bean(StatusUpdateProcessor.class)       
        .end(); // End of route
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't do it?" What is the issue? Please edit to provide a [mcve], complete with all relevant details, to help others help you.

Comment: The `from` endpoint might not be correct. Are you mean to use a `cron:tab?schedule=0/1+*+*+*+*+?` instead of just `cronJob`. [Here](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/cron-component.html#_usage) are some examples on how to use `cron`.

Comment: Hello, I dont  use cron tab, I edited the code i used cron job in the app properties, please check the code again

Comment: Hi, I would recommend just put the `timer` endpoint directly in your `from` endpoint e.g. `from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1")`  otherwise use string interpolation to pass config properties to your endpoints e.g. `apache.cronJob=timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1` then your from should look like: `from("${apache.cronJob}")`

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you tell me, please if the repeat count is 1 , if the code is deployed on docker at what trigger it fires. or when it actually called? is it when I run the the pipeline of the repository, or when I restart the web app server also